# Does Sysprep require the same Service Pack Level on the .clg file with Windows 7 Pro.?

Tags: windows-7, clone, sysprep

I have a Windows 7 Pro. 64bit DVD.  I am using sysprep.

The machine I want to sysprep is Windows 7 Pro. 64bit **SP1**.  My DVD to get the .clg catalog file off of is *not* SP!, just Windows 7 Pro. 64bit.

Can I use the non-SP1 for this purpose?

Comment: No; the entire point of sysprep is you can create a new .wim file and use that when you install windows

Comment: @Ramhound There aren't new things on the SP1 file that might blow up?

Comment: Your creating your own installation disk are you not?  The file should be located in your WinSXS folder

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks.  Didn't know that.  I will investigate.